# Reduce risk of large child support payments for life

Tags: united-states, contract-law, finance, child-support, custody

Lets say hypothetically there is a man and a women. The man makes a relatively high income and is involved romantically with the women.

The women asks the man frequently to have a child with her. The man is hesitant as while he thinks it is unlikely he is aware that once the child is born the women could file for child support, try to gain full custody, and result in him not being able to be around his own child and also having to deal with large child support payments.

The child is then born and what the man feared occurs.

In hindsight is there ANY way the man could've prevented that from happening by before the child is conceived they sign a contract or come up with some other legal means to say essentially:

"Hey I will have a child with you but I want to make sure if in the event of the relationship souring I don't get financially taken to the cleaners and I never lose custody of the child"

Let's say hypothetically this is in the United States and in New York State

Comment: why are these questions always phrased as hypotheticals when it is obvious this happened to you or you are worried about this happening to you?

Answer (score 2):

The way to prevent this is to not have sex.  It takes two to figuratively tango.  To avoid having no custody of a child, not being a bum would be a way to start.  It is extremely unlikely that courts will award sole custody to one parent, absent real problematic behavior by the other parent.

Preconception agreements exist, and are used for sperm donors or the equivalent.  This is really not a vehicle for protection from child support from a regular sexual relationship, and you might find it difficult to enforce if used for such.  State laws will matter a lot here. A coparenting agreement would have a better chance in court.  Remember that the child will have rights that the mother cannot sign away.